# Free Android alternative to Spotify outside the US

Tags: gratis, android, music

I'm looking for a free music on demand app available on Android.

- Similar to [Spotify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appmakr.app303302) or [Deezer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=deezer.android.app)
- Must be free
- Native Android app
- Must be available outside the US, I live in Lebanon. I see many apps that are not available in my country.
- Offline mode is optional not a must.

Comment: Are Spotify or Deezer not available in Lebanon?

Comment: @FranckDemoncourt deezet yes, spotify no... but none of them are free

Comment: Not available - in the Playstore, or when installed? In the first case, use a VPN to install the app.

Comment: @rxt even so, still paid